# Best practices for storing data in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

So let's say I have multiple types things I'd like to store in MongoDB. We'll call them `people`, `places`, and `things`. Things can be at places, people can be at places, and people can have a list of things associated with them. In SQL development I'd have a lot of keys and the like... but this is my first time designing a database in Mongo.

- Since there are no tables, do I give people, places, and things, their own database? Or do I just store them all together, and maybe give each entry a "type" to be selected by?

Comment: Start here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/

Comment: Have you actually read documentation before posting this? Mongo has a lot of explanations what they consider best practice.

Comment: I googled a lot. Didn't find much because I didn't know what search terms to use. Stack overflow consistently has high SEO value on google, so asking here and getting a pointer to the best locations and tutorials for learning this stuff helps the web as a whole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alternative for a table in `mongoDB` is a `collection`. `MongoDB` is not `CouchDB` where you store everything in single giant collection. So you can have a collection called `people`, a collection called `places`, and a one called `things`. Well, documents in `mongoDB` can be embedded within other documents and this usually makes your queries fast. However, embedding documents is not ideal in all cases. Sometimes you need to reference some documents.
Consider reading the documentation of mongoDB and I recommend you reading [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/MongoDB-Applied-Design-Patterns-Copeland/dp/1449340040/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1397427256&sr=8-1&keywords=mongodb%20design%20patterns)

Comment: Or take a glance at this free mongo tutorials https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models/